# Fixing WordPress navbar alignment on mobile devices (responsive)

Tags: css, wordpress

Website: www.tarbooshla.com

When viewed on a mobile device, the search icon is not aligned with the rest of the navbar (the logo and the menu icon). How can I fix this?

I have tried updating all the themes and plugins to no avail.

Comment: You need to write some code to modify this layout. It can be done via CSS but with a dirty hack. If you can edit the template files and know some HTML, I recommend edit your header.php file and rearrange the element.

Comment: Is there a quick fix, where I can just push the logo to the left when the browser is resized to the size of a mobile device? Thus, making enough space for the menu and search icon?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be displaying exactly as intended with the current rule set. I'm assuming you want it to populate on the right? I was able to move it substantially with the padding property, however I don't think that's the best scenario for you. The search icon is currently not text at all, but a pseudo element displayed in an `::before` scenario, if you want it to show up after when it reaches a certain size, I recommend having a media query that sets it to `display:none;` and an `::after` pseudo element that displays when it gets to your smart phone `@media and screen (max-width)` size.

Comment: Wait, you got it to align properly using the padding property? Do tell.

Comment: Oh, no haha. I was not able to get it to align properly with the align property. I have no idea exactly where you want to move it to. If it wasn't far I was just letting you know that, with my knowledge and the inspect element chrome extension, it is not immovable. It seems like your needs are a reordering of the html and possibly some additional css, like another user mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of the limited space in mobile devices.So what you can do is go inside the header.php and put the search bar inside the main navigation bar along with home,about us, etc so search will appear once the user press menu button.or with the help of css,align the menu to the left so that search button can fit into the right.

Comment: What if I push the logo to the left when the size of the browser shrinks? I would rather do that, the thing is, I am not familiar with editing files in WordPress--do you know how I can adjust the rule using CSS--so when the browser shrinks (near mobile device size) the logo can align to the left, thus making room for the search icon and menu icon to be on the right?

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you. Make sure to add this CSS code at a place so that it loads after all other css is loaded ( therefore taking maximum priority )

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #Top_bar .logo {
        text-align: left;
    }

    #Top_bar .top_bar_left {
        float: left;
        width: 80% !important;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background: none !important;
    }

    .header-classic #Top_bar .top_bar_right {
        top: 15px;
        float: right;
    }

}
```